# The certificate for this server is invalid error when startForUploadPhoto using facebook sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

My code is like :

```
    [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] 
        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
          NSLog(@"%@",error);
     }
    }];
```

The error is :

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"

UserInfo=0x933e390 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 

"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be 
“graph.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."

 UserInfo=0x9338700 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?sdk=ios&access_token=BAAEPZAb5iLukBADkyh9M8guUFRJwXuGKI6HnZAZAwMvpQtv3RKsD6M62J4inW1oG8DmY5l81pIz4MhcRHMbLsUAlxEqWq557pYCHXqoF9Gv3FdRTrV9Ai3QuL6zBeM7OoSWvOKlFt1fZAx5h0wkh&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&format=json,

 NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, 

NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?sdk=ios&access_token=BAAEPZAb5iLukBADkyh9M8guUFRJwXuGKI6HnZAZAwMvpQtv3RKsD6M62J4inW1oG8DmY5l81pIz4MhcRHMbLsUAlxEqWq557pYCHXqoF9Gv3FdRTrV9Ai3QuL6zBeM7OoSWvOKlFt1fZAx5h0wkh&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&format=json, 

NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid.You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “graph.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.,

 NSUnderlyingError=0xa32e810 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a
 server that is pretending to be “graph.facebook.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", 
NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200}
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: I finally change my network , and it works.